# Mod_rewrite - rewrite conditions aren't working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm building a php framework that redirects all traffic to ROOT/public/index.php and then puts the url in a get request. My problem is that my RewriteConds aren't working and are accepting files and foldernames.

**in root directory**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]

</IfModule>

<files .htaccess>

 order allow,deny
 deny from all

</files>
```

**in public directory**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: quick question are u running it on http://localhost/ or are you running it on a DS

Comment: not running on localhost

Comment: Remove the if statement, wastes resources and not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[L]` flag tells Apache to stop the redirection after the rule was matched. So assuming your ROOT folder comes first, it will run and stop at the redirection, which would render the second redirect useless.

To fix the problem have this:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule    ^$    public/   
 RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect even existing files and directories to your script:

in public directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

My 2 cent tip: remove the `?url$1` part, and see what's in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead.

Comment: If I take out those lines then `$_GET['url']` will always be index.php and that's not what I want. I'm guessing that's why you're suggesting `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Thanks for your answer, but not what I'm looking for.